# How do you convert A1 Notation into GridRange for Google Spreadsheet API

Tags: kotlin, google-sheets-api

The Google Sheet API, in some cases, requires the expression of range using a `GridRange`, for example when you wish to format some cells, as shown here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/formatting

However, I cannot find any conversion utility from [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#expandable-1), e.g. `Sheet2!A3:B4` into [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/GridRange.html).

There are two difficulties, the first is knowing what `sheetId` corresponds to the named sheet and the second encoding the range into 0-based indices

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.  First you need a live lookup to discover the `sheetId`

In Kotlin:

```kotlin
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets

fun getSheetId(sheets: Sheets, spreadsheetId: String, sheetName: String): Int {
    val spreadsheet = sheets.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId).execute()
    val sheet = spreadsheet.sheets.firstOrNull { it.properties.title == sheetName }
    requireNotNull(sheet) {
        "Sheet $sheetName not found, only found these sheets: " +
                spreadsheet.sheets.map { it.properties.title }.joinToString()
    }
    return sheet.properties.sheetId
}
```

Then to translate the coordinates I used a dependency from Apache POI.  A better solution would be recode the 2 classes you need from there, since POI is big and brings other dependencies in turn you may not want:

- https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/index.html?org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html
- https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddress.html

```kotlin
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.GridRange
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference

fun convertToGridRange(sheets: Sheets, spreadsheetId: String, range: String): GridRange {
    val sheetName = CellReference(range.substringBefore(":")).sheetName
    val cr = CellRangeAddress.valueOf(range)
    return GridRange().apply {
        sheetId = getSheetId(sheets, spreadsheetId, sheetName)
        startRowIndex = cr.firstRow
        startColumnIndex = cr.firstColumn
        endRowIndex = cr.lastRow + 1
        endColumnIndex = cr.lastColumn + 1
    }
}
```

Unit Test

```
@Test
fun convertToGridRangeTest() {
    val gr = googleSpreadsheetService.convertToGridRange(TEST_SHEET, "Sheet2!A3:B4")
    gr.sheetId shouldBe 413044831
    gr.startRowIndex shouldBe 2
    gr.startColumnIndex shouldBe 0
    gr.endRowIndex shouldBe 4
    gr.endColumnIndex shouldBe 2
}
```

Dependencies are:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-sheets
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi